# Search a multi-valued field with a self join

Tags: search, solr

I have the following (simplified) solr schema:

```
<schema name="documents" version="1.1">
  <uniqueKey>id</uniqueKey>
  ...
  <fields>
    <field
      name="id"
      type="string"
      indexed="true"
      stored="true"
      required="true"/>
    <field
      name="documentReferences"
      type="string"
      indexed="true"
      stored="false"
      multiValued="true"
      required="false"/>
    </fields>
</schema>
```

The values which will be in this `documentReferences` field are all `ids` of other `documents` which are indexed in this solr core.

The search I want to accomplish (in english):

```
Documents who's id is not in any other document's documentReferences field
```

Is this possible? I don't have a problem indexing another field if it would help answer this question.

Answer (score 0):

One of the Solution, I was thinking of was

1. Index the Id with the Document references itself, that would make sure if the document is not referenced by any other document the count would be one for sure
2. Search for All Documents Facet on the Document references and then filter the facets with count 1, which would be the list of the ids not refered by the other ids
3. Would have loved to use the [facet maxcount](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SOLR-4411) param which would have limited the results for the search out of the box.